# Constructor, subclass method called from base and instance member order initialization problem

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to design a small base abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    abstract void reload();


    protected BaseClass()
    {
        reload();
        // schedule reload for every X minutes
    }
}
```

Now, subclass:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
    private int member = 5;

    @Override
    void reload()
    {
        member = 20;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that reload() method is called before the member is initialized. Thus, member is assigned 20 and afterwards, assigned with the value 5. (this is only an example of course, the actual code is different, but the same idea).
What is the best design for what I'm trying to achieve?
I want the order of the initialization to be - member assigned 5, and if reload() fails for some reason i want it to stay with the initial value. However in this code, 5 overrides the value of reload(). If I don't assign an initial value for the instance member, it works of course.
Is it possible what I'm asking?

Comment: How do you know that reload failed?

Comment: If you are going to set member to 20 anyways, why set it to 5 first?

Comment: Don't call non-final methods in a constructor. "Effective Java" contains a good explanation.

Comment: @sweeper im giving an initial value in case the reload fails (for example the reload fetch data from DB and might fail). In this case, i want the default value to remain

Comment: I accepted as duplicate. So what I'm trying to do is basically, impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a builder to achieve that.

This way you can achieve full control.

```
public abstract class Foo {

    public abstract void postConstruct();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = Foo.build(Bar.class);
        System.out.println(bar);

    }

    public static <T extends Foo> T build(Class<T> clazz) {
        T obj;
        try {
            obj = clazz.newInstance();
            obj.postConstruct();
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "Class "+clazz.getName()+" is not a valid class",e);
        }
    }

}


public class Bar extends Foo {

    int value = 10;

    protected Bar() {
        super();
    }

    public void postConstruct() {
        value = 7;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bar [value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is nice but a bit overkill for my use case, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the constructor  and call reload() there but do not call super(), this might not be acceptable for other reasons :)

```
class SubClass { 
    private int member = 5;

    public SubClass() {
        reload();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: No that doesnt work, base constructor is always called explicitly

Comment: @paranoidAndroid Not sure what you mean, this works for me. And it also works when calling super() in the constructor.